# Displaying Start-End Date in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created email workflow which will trigger biweekly. I have to show To Date-From Date in the email body based on the record Created On field. I am not using any custom code, as I am new to dynamics and don't have developer background. For To date, I can use record Created On field but how to calculate End Date based on Created On.

Answer (score 0):

If End Date is always a set amount of time after the Start Date, you can specify this in an update step of the workflow. For example, you can set it to 14 days after the Start Date:

[image]

You can also use the date when the workflow runs:

[image]